# Arrary Variable used in range

Tags: excel, vba

```
Sub Bingo()

Dim Bingo(75) As String
Dim rndNum As Integer
Dim count As Integer

For j = 1 To 75

    If j >= 1 And j < 16 Then Bingo(j) = "B" & j
    If j >= 16 And j < 31 Then Bingo(j) = "I" & j
    If j >= 31 And j < 46 Then Bingo(j) = "N" & j
    If j >= 46 And j < 61 Then Bingo(j) = "G" & j
    If j >= 61 And j < 76 Then Bingo(j) = "O" & j

    Debug.Print Bingo(j)

Next j

count = 0

Do Until count > 75

count = count + 1

MsgBox "Please press OK to continue"

Redraw:

Randomize

rndNum = Int((75 - 1 + 1) * Rnd + 1)

If Bingo(rndNum) = "" Then

    GoTo Redraw

Else

    Sheet1.Range(L13).Value = Bingo(rndNum)
    Sheet1.Range("A" & count) = Bingo(rndNum)
    Bingo(rndNum) = ""


End If
```

Comment: I get an error when trying to place values in Sheet1.range("L13") and column A.  I dont understand how to work with arrary variables.

Comment: Please add that detail to your question by [edit]ing it.

Comment: you are missing the `""` around the address for the range.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is problematic for a couple reasons, the primary of which is that it's likely to run for a VERY long time. Since you're erasing a value from your array each time you use it, you'll eventually get to a state where you have an array of 74 blanks and only one value --- and you're waiting for a random number generator to randomly generate the index of that last value in the array. You'll be waiting a long time.

Here's an example solution that creates a `Collection` instead of an array. The reason I use a collection here is to easily remove an entry after we add it to the worksheet.

```
Option Explicit

Sub MyBingo()
    Dim bingoValues As Collection
    Set bingoValues = New Collection

    With bingoValues
        Dim i As Long
        For i = 1 To 75
            If i >= 1 And i < 16 Then .Add "B" & i
            If i >= 16 And i < 31 Then .Add "I" & i
            If i >= 31 And i < 46 Then .Add "N" & i
            If i >= 46 And i < 61 Then .Add "G" & i
            If i >= 61 And i < 76 Then .Add "O" & i
        Next i

        Dim thisRow As Long
        thisRow = 1

        Do While .Count > 0
            '--- get a random index from 1 to however many values
            '    remain in the collection
            Dim index As Long
            index = Int((.Count - 1 + 1) * Rnd + 1)
            Sheet1.Range("L13").Value = .Item(index)
            Sheet1.Cells(thisRow, 1).Value = .Item(index)
            .Remove index
            thisRow = thisRow + 1
        Loop

    End With

End Sub
```